# Prestashop list 2 products in 1 <li>

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I have a slider that list 4

pr slide.

I want to add an extra row so it will show 2x4 products.

To make it happen I need to list 2 products pr.

I have really tried to fix it but there is something wrong with my code and how I count my products.

Please take a look:`{if isset($products)}
    
    {include file="$tpl_dir./breadcrumb.tpl"}
    
        
        {assign var=count value=0}

```
    {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}

        {if $count == 0}
            <li style="position: relative;">
        {/if}
            <div id="ProductCon">
                <div class="prodimage"><a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="product_img_link" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"><img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home')}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} /></a></div>
                <h3><a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></h3>
            </div>
            {if $count == 1}
                </li>
            {/if}
            {function name='counter2'}
                {$count+1}
            {/function}
    {/foreach}



    </ul>
</div>
<!-`
```

Comment: Can you share the current template code before the modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably check the index value in the foreach loop. Here is an example how you could achieve it. This also checks if the list has odd number of products and closes the li tag for last product. Hope this helps

```
<ul>
    {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
        {if $smarty.foreach.products.first == true || $smarty.foreach.products.index % 2 == 0}
            <li style="position: relative;">
        {/if}
            <div id="ProductCon">
                <div class="prodimage"><a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="product_img_link" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"><img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home')}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} /></a></div>
                <h3><a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></h3>
            </div>
        {if $smarty.foreach.products.index % 2 == 1 || $smarty.foreach.products.last == true}
            </li>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is not a (complete) programming language, it's a templating engine. Some things are purposely not permitted.

You should be using a [counter](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.counter.tpl) which is a prop smarty offers in order for you to not have to use programming logic to achieve your goal.

For assignments you need to use a special Smarty function smarty [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl).

### For smarty counter this should work:

```
{counter start=0 skip=1 assign="count"}

{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
    {if $count == 0}
        <li style="position: relative;">
     {/if}
    <div id="ProductCon">
        <div class="prodimage">
            <a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="product_img_link" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
                <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home')}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
            </a>
        </div>
        <h3>
            <a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    {if $count == 1}
        </li>
    {/if}
    {counter}
{/foreach}
```